# Entity framework error when enable migrations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I already had a database first ASP MVC project. Now I remove .edmx file and and all every thing related to database first and make it code first. When I want to `Enable-Migrations` I get this error in powershell. :

> The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was generated from an EDMX file for either Database First or Model First development.  This will not work correctly. To fix this problem do not remove the line of code that throws this exception. If you wish to use Database First or Model First, then make sure that the Entity Framework connection string is included in the app.config or web.config of the start-up project. If you are creating your own DbConnection, then make sure that it is an EntityConnection and not some other type of DbConnection, and that you pass it to one of the base DbContext constructors that take a DbConnection. To learn more about Code First, Database First, and Model First see the Entity Framework documentation here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=394715

Here is my Connection string in webconfig:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Context" connectionString="Data Source=.\;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\myDbName.mdf;Initial Catalog=myDbName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

And Here is my Context :

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context()
        : base("name=Context")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: is it that UnintentionalCodeFirstException?  I'm assuming you have to delete that line if you want to switch to code first.  I'm guessing it autogenerated that line to prevent you from being able to do code-first migrations.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.unintentionalcodefirstexception(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: exactly what @maembe said. You said originally that you removed "everything related to the database first", but you didn't actually remove and re-create the context. The throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException is specific to database first contexts.

Comment: Are you really asking why the UnintentionalCodeFirstException is thrown, or do you use it to illustrate the throwing line location ? BTW, have you read : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn579398(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Thanks, my problem is solved.